# SQL Server 2008 R2 Management Studio errors

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sharepoint-2013

I had SQL Server 2005 installed on my system. Then I installed SQL Server 2008 R2 also.

Now when I open SQL Server 2008 R2 Management Studio I get two messages.

> (1) You can import customized user settings from SQL Server 2005 Management Studio. Be aware that some default settings might be changed after you import your customized user settings. Do you want to import your customized user settings from SQL Server 2005 Management Studio
>
> (2)There are SQL Server 2005 Management Studio registered services on this system. Do you want to add them into Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio? Adding The Server registration information has no effect on the servers themselves.

What I should answer to this messages? Yes or No? Please help. I am trying to install **Sharepoint Server 2013 Server** on my system. But there is an error when I ran Products configuration wizard.

> Failed to create sample data. An  exception of type
> System.Null.Reference Exception was thrown.

Does the error in SQL server Management Studio have anything to do with this error?

Comment: Those aren't **errors** - they're **information** messages - you can basically move the settings and registered servers from the older Studio to the new one. Unless you have a good reason, I would definitely do this for both question - pick **YES**

Comment: The question isn't related to C# or Visual Studio. Voted to migrate it to dba.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Rather try to google your problem with Sharepoint. http://www.myriadtech.com.au/blog/James/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=57

Answer (score 0):

1st Sql is warning you that you have prev users that are created in the old sql server 2005 instance.

And asking you if you wish to migrate those users to the new sql 2008 instance.

if you would like to **login** with the same **users** that you used to use in the old sql then press **yes** other wise **neglect** the dialog and create your new users in the new sql server.